# How to get input data in textArea

Tags: java, javafx

I am a new programmer in javafx.

Using java FX in IDE I want to make a student information application.

I want to print the input data into the text area but it prints out in the console now.
(After clicking display button I want to show all the input data in textarea)

please help me out to solve this problem.
I am attaching my code below for your suggestion..

Main.java

Comment: I don't understand your question. You have used the textArea.setText/appendText methods already. You just have to use them in your action handler too.

Comment: yes I know but I don't know how to use the codes into the text area.

Comment: Just check available methods for all components.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just place

```
          textArea.setText("Name: " + t1.getText() +"\nAddress: " + t2.getText()
    +"\nProvince: " + t3.getText() +"\nCity: " + t4.getText()
    +"\nPostal Code: " + t5.getText() +"\nPhone Number: " + t6.getText()
    +"\nEmail: " + t7.getText()  + "\nCourses: "+comboBox.getItems()
    + "\nActivities: "+c1.getText()  + "\n"+c2.getText());
```

into the action handler.

And remove the imports

```
import javax.swing.JTextArea;
import java.awt.*;
```

They are not JavaFX.

Answer (score 0):

You are printing your result into the [standard output stream](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/System.html#out) (`System.out`). I assume you want to display what is printed by:

```java
System.out.println("Name: " + t1.getText() +"\nAddress: " + t2.getText()
                    +"\nProvince: " + t3.getText() +"\nCity: " + t4.getText()
                    +"\nPostal Code: " + t5.getText() +"\nPhone Number: " + t6.getText()
                    +"\nEmail: " + t7.getText()  + "\nCourses: "+comboBox.getItems()
                    + "\nActivities: "+c1.getText()  + "\n"+c2.getText());
```

Please visit [the documentation of the TextArea class](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/control/TextArea.html). Printing your result into the standard output stream has nothing to do with printing your result in your TextArea. Simply use a normal String that contains your result and set the text of your TextArea accordingly.